# What's the best strategy for having multiple captcha image at the same time?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, captcha, recaptcha

Let me explain the problem by giving an example:
Imagine that we are creating a blog application which in users can leave comments, so we need to ensure if a user is a human or not. Keep it in mind that due to some limitations, I can't use Google reCaptcha, so I have to create my own captcha code.

So far there is no problem since there are a bunch of samples on the internet and most of them use Sessions to keep last created code and some of them use an encrypted key, in URL or a hidden input in forms.

Firstly, if I use Sessions I'm not able to display several blog posts which contain a unique captcha code that I can validate them after user submission because I just keep the last generated random code.

Secondly, if I use an encrypted key and reveal it in output HTML or in query string it would be easy for robots to use a generated key several times unless I store these keys after submission. But if I choose to use disposable keys I have to search my database every time to prevent generating duplicated random code.

The question is What's the best approach to let users open several posts and leave comment for each one with less code and I/O complexity.

Comment: So tell me - why do you need different captchas on a page?

Comment: Thank you @u_mulder. I don't need multiple captchas on one page I'm talking about opening several pages that each one has its own captcha which differs from other pages captcha.

Comment: Use an encrypted key which also includes a datetime. Then when you decrypt it, you will know how old it is and can block bots from using old ones.

Comment: Could you clarify this part 'if I use Sessions I'm not able to display several blog posts which contain a unique captcha code that I can validate them after user submission because I just keep the last generated random code' ?